# Compute intersection of two arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given two arrays of unequal length:

```
var arr1 = ["mike", "sue", "tom", "kathy", "henry"]; //arr1.length = 5
var arr2 = ["howey", "jim", "sue", "jennifer", "kathy", "hank", "alex"]; //arr2.length = 7
```

How can I find the values common to both arrays?  In this case `"sue"` and `"kathy"` should be returned.

Answer (score 60):

Here is an intersection function based on [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
function intersect(a, b) {
    var t;
    if (b.length > a.length) t = b, b = a, a = t; // indexOf to loop over shorter
    return a.filter(function (e) {
        return b.indexOf(e) > -1;
    });
}

var arr1 = ["mike", "sue", "tom", "kathy", "henry"];
    arr2 = ["howey", "jim", "sue", "jennifer", "kathy", "hank", "alex"];

intersect(arr1, arr2); // ["sue", "kathy"]
```

---

You might also want to consider the following

```
var arr1 = ['sue', 'sue', 'kathy'],
    arr2 = ['kathy', 'kathy', 'sue'];
```

The above would now give `["sue", "sue", "kathy"]`. If you don't want duplicates you could do a further filter on this. This would also standardise results. i.e.

```
return a
    .filter(/* .. */) // same as before
    .filter(function (e, i, c) { // extra step to remove duplicates
        return c.indexOf(e) === i;
    });
```

Adding this will now return the same result as the previous arrays (`["sue", "kathy"]`), even though there were duplicates.

Comment: Thanks Paul for giving both the remove dupes and regular options, Nice bit of code.

Comment: I dont believe this will work if one of the two arrays is empty, it will return a false positive...I simply did a check added a check for .length

Comment: Arghh.. I hate `if (condition) return true;` construction.. Why not `return condition;`?

Comment: @vp_arth to make it more obvious what's going on, of course feel free to modify it if you decide to use the code

Comment: `[1]`,`[1,1]` shouldn't it return [1] ?

Comment: @afreeland If one is empty, an empty array will be returned (right?). Is this not the intended behavior?

Comment: Removing duplicates from the starting array before comparing its items with others might be a bit more efficient, especially if there is a large number of duplicates.

Answer (score 57):

You could use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var result = arr1.filter(function(n) {
  return arr2.indexOf(n) > -1;
});
```

Comment: Why not just `return arr2.indexOf(n) !== -1`? You're making a new array either way.

Comment: @alex filter() returns array of matched values, while forEach does not return anything.

Comment: This should be marked as the accepted answer

Comment: @Blender  7 years later...  "Why not just..."  prolly conventional C/C++ paranoia.

Answer (score 25):

You want to find the intersection of two arrays?

You could use Underscore's [`intersection()`](http://underscorejs.org/#intersection). This will give you a list of values present in both arrays.

```
var commonValues = _.intersection(arr1, arr2);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EwPUX/).

If you didn't want to use a library, it'd be trivial to implement...

```
var commonValues = arr1.filter(function(value) { 
                                   return arr2.indexOf(value) > -1;
                               });
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CResY/).

If `Array.prototype.filter()` and `Array.prototype.indexOf()` are not supported in your target platforms...

```
var commonValues = [];
var i, j;
var arr1Length = arr1.length;
var arr2Length = arr2.length;

for (i = 0; i < arr1Length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < arr2Length; j++) {
        if (arr1[i] === arr2[j]) {
            commonValues.push(arr1[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kJTZ3/).

Comment: Reading this made me start thinking.. what should the expected result of an intersection be if you have `"sue"` appearing _multiple times_ in one/both of the arrays?

Comment: @PaulS. Interesting thoughts. I guess this would add it multiple times if it were in the source array multiple times. If it were an issue, you could use a *drop duplicates* type method on the result (or factor it as you went in the above code).

Answer (score 9):

Iterate over one of the arrays and compare the objects with the other:

```
var results = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    if (arr2.indexOf(arr1[i]) !== -1) {
        results.push(arr1[i]);
    }
}
```