# Typescript: matches 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to find out if 2 arrays match (have common elements) in one or more elements.

Is there a more elegant way than the 2 loops?

In Java I would use a stream with lambda.

```
lst1.stream ().anyMatch (c -> lst2.contains (c))
```

But I am not sure hot to do that in Typescript/Javascript.

```
let lst1 : string [] = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"];
let lst2 : string [] = ["ddd", "eee", "bbb"];    // 1 match at "bbb"

let matches : boolean = false;
for (let a of this.lst1)
{
    for (let b of this.lst2)
    {
        if (a == b)
        {
            matches = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 2 loops is the minimum but you can make the code shorter.  `let matches = lst1.some(item => lst2.includes(item))`

Comment: The answers are good but you should **really** [avoid the double equals operator in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness). Use triple equals `===`. You should also avoid the whitesmith/allman style braces and use [K&R braces because of automatic semicolon insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218756/javascript-braces-on-new-line-or-not).

Comment: "elegance" is a matter of opinion; algorithmically, using built-in list processing functions is really the same as "2 loops" if they're based on iteration. A database engine would (sometimes) use a "hash join" to be more efficient in a situation like this.

Comment: Related: [`Set.prototype.intersection()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/intersection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function combined with the [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) function?

For example:

```
const matches = this.lst1.some(x => this.lst2.includes(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
lst1.filter(x => lst2.includes(x))
```

would return array of overlaps

Answer (score -1):

Javascript has built-in array functions which can help abstract tasks like this. Particularly `Array.prototype.filter` should be of use in your case.

The question has been asked before however, so consider taking a look at this answer (or other answers on this question): https://stackoverflow.com/a/16227294/14775245